# Tensor shape changes in tf.while_loop()

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, deep-learning, tensor

```
    # initialize start token
    target = tf.constant([[2]], dtype=tf.int32, shape=[1, 1])     # 2 - <BOS>

    dummy_outputs = [4, 7, 1, 9, 15, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  # for testing
    self.max_length = 10
    def generate_next_token(tar):
        # out, _ = self.model([features, tf.expand_dims(tar, 0)], training=False) # shape: [1, seq_length, vocab_size]
        # out = out[:, -1, :]  # take last token of sequence. shape: [1, vocab_size]
        # out = tf.random.categorical(out, 1)  # shape: [1, 1]
        # out = tf.cast(out, tf.int32)
        out = tf.constant([[dummy_outputs.pop(0)]], dtype=tf.int32, shape=[1, 1])
        print(tar.shape)
        tar = tf.concat([tar, out], axis=-1)
        return tar

    def end_of_sequence_not_reached(tar):
        print(tar.shape)
        return tf.math.logical_and(tf.less(tf.shape(tar)[-1], self.max_length),
                                   tf.not_equal(tar[-1], 3)) # 3 - <EOS>

    target = tf.while_loop(cond=end_of_sequence_not_reached, body=generate_next_token, loop_vars=[target], shape_invariants=[tf.TensorShape([1, None])])
```

Somehow, the shape of `tar` changes from `(1, n)` to `(n)` after every iteration of the tf.while_loop, and dimensions of length 1 are lost,  so I have to work around it by doing

```
    if len(tar.shape) < len(prev_shape):
        tar = tf.expand_dims(tar, 0)
```

Why is this and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do and what is your desired result?

Comment: I'm trying to generate a sequence from a sequence model. I have built a subclassed model that does some preprocessing, calls the sequence model in its call() function to generate one token, appends the token to the sequence, then repeats this using tf.while_loop() till the full sequence is generated. At first, the sequence is shaped [1, 1], but somehow after an iteration of the while loop the shape changes to [2] rather than [1, 2].

Comment: can you show what is your desired result?

Comment: The last dimension of the sequence should increase by one after every iteration, and at the end, the shape should be [1, seq_length], say the (arbitrary) sequence length is 5, it should be something like [[2, 7, 9, 5, 3]].

Comment: The while_loop should stop either when the length of the sequence is greater than max_length, or the last generated token is 3 which represents <EOS> (end of sequence).